# problem in sending base64 data in GET request

Tags: node.js, fs, async.js

Hi I am facing issues sending base64 data in GET request.
I was successful in converting the image into base64 data and inserting it in **receivedFile**
but during response the attachments come as an empty array while the rest of the data i.e user_id is flowing successfully.

Hence if you could please help me to resolve this issue.

Below is the code

router.js

```
router.get('/users/data/expand/:nid',async (req,res) => {
    var idselected = req.params.nid;
    var dir = '\images';
    var receivedFile = [];    
      try {
           const checkData = await user.find({"user_id": idselected});   
             
            await checkData[0].attachments.forEach (element => {
            
            fs.readdir(dir,function(err,files)  {
              
                if(err) {
                    console.log(err)
                }else {
                files.forEach((filename) => {
                    filename = element;
                    fs.readFile(filename,'base64', (err,base64Data) => {
                      if(err) {
                           console.log(err);  
                       }
                       
                      receivedFile.push(base64Data);
                       
                          
                    })
                })
                }
                
           })
          })
            //issue is here the attachments is coming as empty instead of base64 data 
            const returnUser = new User({
                    user_id: checkData.user_id,
                    attachments: receivedFile    
                })
          res.status(201).send(returnUser);
    }      
       catch(e) { 
      
        res.status(500).send(e)
     
    } 
})
```

Comment: The `forEach` method always returns `undefined` so `await`ing it is probably not behaving as you expected. You could fix it by using promisified versions of `fs.readdir` and `fs.readFile` and using the `await` there.

Comment: hi Diego tried the method u recommended but still facing issues

Comment: below are the changes in the lines I made :
fs.promises.readdir(dir,function(err,files)
fs.readFileAsync (filename , {encoding:'base64'} , (err,base64Data)

Comment: I added this before GET request : 
const util = require('util');
fs.readFileAsync = util.promisify(fs.readFile);

Comment: I cannot know how your code looks like from the messages you sent. But, have you also added the `await` to the fs related function calls.

Comment: I tried adding it but it gives me the error : await is only valid in async function 
additionally could it be possible if you can show me the changes u r recommanding by making changes in the above code

Comment: You're totally right. For that to work the `forEach` would need to be replaced with a regular `for` loop. The other option is to `.map` the result of `fs.readdir` into a list of promises and then use `Promise.all`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224794/discussion-between-diego-and-akhil-modi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well its always good to create helper functions and to promisfy it so you can use `async / await` syntax.

I have changed your code. I didnt tested it but i guess it should work:#

```
router.get("/users/data/expand/:nid", async (req, res) => {
  var idselected = req.params.nid;
  var dir = "images";
  try {
    const checkData = await user.findOne({ user_id: idselected });

    let receivedFile = await Promise.all(
      checkData.attachments.flatMap(async element => {
        let files = await readDirectory(dir);
        return await Promise.all(
          files.map(filename => {
            filename = element;
            return readFile(filename)
          })
        );
      })
    );
    const returnUser = new User({
      user_id: checkData.user_id,
      attachments: receivedFile
    });
    let savedUser = await returnUser.save();
    res.status(201).send(savedUser);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).send(e);
  }
});

function readDirectory(dir) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    fs.readdir(dir, function(err, files) {
      if (err) {
        rej(err);
      } else {
        res(files);
      }
    });
  });
}

function readFile(filename) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    fs.readFile(filename, "base64", (err, base64Data) => {
      if (err) {
        rej(err);
      }
      res(base64Data);
    });
  });
}
```

I guess you use mongoose.

There is an method called `findOne` and also you forgot to save your model with `returnUser.save()`

Comment: @akhilmodi ok good. i have no idea if it would work i just wrote it down out of my head